# When I try to install Ubuntu 18.04 I get "please update microcode to version 0x25"

Tags: system-installation, intel, 18.04

I want to install dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04 from asus a455lf laptop, but there is a warning

> please update microcode to version 0x25.

I've updated the BIOS but it's still the same.

Comment: Please add more info, is the message shown when booting the ubuntu thumb drive? During the actual installation? After? Can you check the flash drive for errors?